# How Do I Accumulate a Class Field using an Array?

Tags: java, object, arraylist

When I am trying to accumulate the `albumPrice` field it does not update. 
What I need is for the price to update with each album and then also output the `totalPaid` value.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArtistList {
    static DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("$###.00");
    private String artistName = null;
    private Double price = 0.0;
    private String albumName = null;
    private String albumYear = null;
    private Double totalPaid = 0.0;
    private Double priceOut = 0.0;

    ArtistList(String thisArtist, String thisAlbum, String thisYear, double thisPrice) {
        artistName = thisArtist;
        albumName = thisAlbum;
        albumYear = thisYear;
        price = thisPrice;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int size = 0;

        ArrayList<ArtistList> artists = new ArrayList<ArtistList>();

        artists.add(new ArtistList("Dave Matthews Band", "Under The Table and Dreaming", "1994", 12.12));
        artists.add(new ArtistList("Stone Temple Pilots", "Core", "1992", 5.99));
        artists.add(new ArtistList("Incubus", "Make Yourself", "1999", 5.89));
        size = artists.size();
        System.out.println("We have " + size + " artists");

        for (ArtistList out : artists) {
            System.out.println(out);
        }

        for (@SuppressWarnings("unused") ArtistList out : artists) {
            priceOut = priceTotal(price);
        }

        // for(@SuppressWarnings("unused") ArtistList out: artists){
        //               totalPaid+=price;
        //  }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Total paid for inventory" + " " + f.format(priceOut));
    }

    public String toString() {
        return artistName + ", " + albumName + ", " + albumYear + ", " + f.format(price);
    }

    public Double priceTotal(Double price) {
        return totalPaid += price;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do the properties `price` and `albumPrice` refer to (in an `ArtistList`)? Your code contains not one line of comment...

Comment: Apologies...got it squared away. Changed the variable from a class field to a variable declared in the main()

Comment: Are you sure you are not confusing `Double` and `double` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the main method inside the the class, it will run first and there will no be an instance of the class it self so that the private variables will not be initiated when using the main method so you have to set them static in case you want to use them.

you can seperate the main method in a separate class then inform getters and setters for the private fields.

```
Class TestArtistList{
public class ArtistList{
    // TODO declare the fields with getters and setters and the methods
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO your test code

    ArrayList<ArtistList> artists = new ArrayList<ArtistList>();

    artists.add(new ArtistList("Dave Matthews Band", "Under The Table and Dreaming", "1994", 12.12));
    artists.add(new ArtistList("Stone Temple Pilots", "Core", "1992", 5.99));
    artists.add(new ArtistList("Incubus", "Make Yourself", "1999", 5.89));
    size = artists.size();
    System.out.println("We have " + size + " artists");

    for (ArtistList out : artists) {
        System.out.println(out);
    }

    for (@SuppressWarnings("unused") ArtistList out : artists) {
        out.priceOut = priceTotal(out.price);
    }
}
}
```